# initiating the uninstallation of a python application within the application itself

Tags: python, windows, py2exe, windows-installer

I have an application written in python and freezed using py2exe and bundled as an msi using wix. what I am trying to achieve is providing a way to uninstall the application directly from the application. To do that I am running the following command as a subprocess inside python

```
command = "MsiExec /x{product-code of the application} /qn"
process = subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out = process.communicate()
```

my question is will the above code snippet uninstalls application even it is running, secondly if I trigger the uninstallation and close the main application will the uninstallation continue ? or the child process dies with parent ?

Comment: Have you tried this ? My suspicion is that this would not work as the application is open and would prompt you to close it.

Comment: @Guyver3 I haven't tried it but I know it will block on the line `out = process.communicate()`

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the uninstall and quit to avoid locked files. MSIExec will continue running.  Even then that's not the real problem as MSI can probably delete it anyways with or without the help of a reboot.

The real problem is your process needs to already be elevated for /qn to work.  MSI doesn't do a UAC prompt from a standard user when running silently.  /qb would.

Either that or perhaps your application is installed per user and doesn't need elevation.